# What is function binding in python?

Tags: python, kivy

I was trying to understand the kivy library in python. Below is the complete code.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.inside.name)
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Name: "))

        self.inside.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.inside.name)
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Email: "))

        self.inside.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.inside.name)
        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text="Phno: "))

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text="Submit", font_size=40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
        self.add_widget(self.submit)        

    def pressed(self, instance):
        print("pressed")



class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Here, while in `MyGrid` class, under init method, when I try to bind the submit button(`self.submit.bind`) with the `pressed` method, the argument with on_press doesn't include parentheses.

```
self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
```

Why does it work? Is it because it's a python convention to not include parentheses while passing it to a method?
And what is the use of the instance argument in the pressed method?

Comment: `self.pressed` is a reference to the instance's `MyGrid.pressed` method. You don't want to actually call the method on that line of code, you just want the reference to be stored away so it can be called later.

Comment: In python, functions are objects. Without the parentheses, you are passing the function object as an argument - this is pretty typical when binding a callback function. This is saying "execute this function when the on_press event is fired". If you were to add the parentheses, you would be explicitly calling the function, evaluating it, and trying to bind the return value of that function as a callback, which does not make sense (unless that function returns a function object).

Comment: @PeterWood thank you, could you explain the use of instance argument in 
 the pressed method?

Comment: @py_G I know very little about kivy. I would have thought the documentation would explain, and [it does](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html). You could feasibly bind the same processing function to the `on_press` callback of multiple buttons. To distinguish the button it is passed as the `instance` parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass the function without parentheses, you are passing the function object itself

```
self.submit.bind(on_press=self.pressed)
```

This is generally used for callback mechanisms, among other things. If you added parentheses, `self.pressed()` would be invoked immediately at that very statement, instead of `on_press` saving that function to call later, in response to a button click.

Comment: You are not passed a function object. You are passed an instance of `method`, created on demand by the evaluation of the expression `self.pressed`.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses *call* the method. In the cases where you omit them, you're passing the method itself as a callback to be invoked *later*. When the method is called, parentheses are involved, but not until then.

Answer (score -1):

Python is an Object Oriented Language in the sense that everything is an object (even methods). In the example above the `bind` method takes a callable object as a parameter (so another method).

To get the callable object rather than call the method you omit the brackets.

Comment: Every name refers to an object.

Answer (score -1):

It helps to see what `self.pressed` actually evaluates to.

The instance `self` doesn't have an attribute named `pressed`. Its class, `MyGrid`, has a `function`-valued attribute by that name, though.

So `self.pressed` evaluates to `MyGrid.pressed`. But, because the `function` class implements the descriptor protocol, you don't get a reference to that `function` object. Instead, you get the result of `MyGrid.pressed.__get__(self, MyGrid)`. And *that* returns a callable object of type `method`. That object, when called, will take whatever arguments it receives and immediately pass `self` and those arguments to a call to `MyGrid.pressed`.

In short, the value of `self.pressed` looks a lot like a function that might have been defined like

```
def bound_method(*args, **kwargs):
    return MyGrid.pressed(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

```
self.pressed == MyGrid.pressed
             == MyGrid.__dict__['pressed'].__get__(self, MyGrid)
```

and when `self.pressed` is eventually called,

```
self.pressed(ins) == MyGrid.__dict_['pressed'].__get(self, MyGrid)(self, ins)
```